# $stateParams returning null object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, state

I am trying to get latitude and longitude variables from the URL and assigning them to the 'center' property of Google Maps. I am not getting any errors but I alert my center object to the screen, and both 'lat' and 'lon' come up null.

Here is the webpage: http://alainwebdesign.ca/pl4#/49.2/-122.6

Javascript:

```
(function (window, ng) {
    ng.module('app', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps', 'ui.router'])



  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
      $stateProvider.state('location', {
          url: '/:lat/:lon',
          templateUrl: 'searchRadius.html',
          controller: 'MapsCtrl',

          resolve: {
              resolveMap: function (MapService, $stateParams) {
                  return MapService.getData($stateParams.lat, $stateParams.lon);
              }
          }
      });

  })

  .config(['uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider', function (GoogleMapApi) {
      GoogleMapApi.configure({
          key: 'AIzaSyCbRPhVlxgVwBC0bBOgyB-Dn_K8ONrxb_g',
          v: '3',
          libraries: 'weather,geometry,visualization'
      });
  } ])


    .controller('MapsCtrl', ['$scope', "uiGmapLogger", "uiGmapGoogleMapApi", "$interval", "$state", "$stateParams",
      function ($scope, $log, GoogleMapApi, $interval, $state, $stateParams) {
          $log.currentLevel = $log.LEVELS.debug;
          var center = { latitude: parseFloat($stateParams.lat), longitude: parseFloat($stateParams.lon) };
          alert(JSON.stringify(center));
          //Object.freeze(center); caused TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property ('latitude') ...

          console.log($stateParams);

          $scope.map = {
              center: center,
              pan: false,
              zoom: 16,
              refresh: false,
              events: {},
              bounds: {}
          };

          $scope.map.circle = {
              id: 1,
              center: center,
              radius: 500, //(current time - date lost)*km/hour
              stroke: {
                  color: '#08B21F',
                  weight: 2,
                  opacity: 1
              },

              fill: {
                  color: '#08B21F',
                  opacity: 0.5
              },
              geodesic: false, // optional: defaults to false
              draggable: false, // optional: defaults to false
              clickable: true, // optional: defaults to true
              editable: false, // optional: defaults to false
              visible: true, // optional: defaults to true
              events: {
                  dblclick: function () {
                      $log.debug("circle dblclick");
                  },
                  radius_changed: function (gObject) {
                      var radius = gObject.getRadius();
                      $log.debug("circle radius radius_changed " + radius);
                  }
              }
          }





          //Increase Radius:
          $interval(function () {
              $scope.map.circle.radius += 30; //dynamic var
              $state.transitionTo('location', { //location is the state name
                  center: $stateParams.center,
                  radius: $scope.map.circle.radius
              },
    {
        notify: false
    });
          }, 1000); //end of interval function


      } ]); //end of controller

})(window, angular);
```

searchRadius.html:

```
<div style="height: 100%"> <!--took out: ng-if="map.center !== undefined"-->
    <ui-gmap-google-map 
                        center='map.center'
                        zoom='map.zoom'
                        draggable='map.draggable'
                        dragging='map.dragging'
                        refresh='map.refresh'
                        options='map.options'
                        events='map.events'
                        pan='map.pan'>


        <ui-gmap-circle 
                        center='map.circle.center'
                        radius='map.circle.radius'
                        fill='map.circle.fill'
                        stroke='map.circle.stroke'
                        clickable='map.circle.clickable'
                        draggable='map.circle.draggable'
                        editable='map.circle.editable'
                        visible='map.circle.visible'
                        events='map.circle.events'>

        </ui-gmap-circle>


    </ui-gmap-google-map>

</div>
```

index.html:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="example/assets/stylesheets/example.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="website_libs/dev_deps.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.6/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/nmccready/angular-simple-logger/0.0.1/dist/index.js"></script><script src="dist/angular-google-maps_dev_mapped.js"></script>
    <script src="getLoc.js"></script>
    <script src="searchRadius.js"></script>

    <script src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD_g7xCYEi-U54SYfTXQ_lukRsChkWgjXQ'></script>

    <title>Pet Locate</title>

    <!--NEW STUFF FROM TOM-->


</head>

    <body style="height: 100%">
        <ui-view></ui-view>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: did you try logging `$stateParams`? try removing `parseFloat()`?

Comment: @charlietfl yes I already am logging $stateParams (it's about halfway down searchradius.js) and just tried taking out parseFloat() and that resulted in a 'could not find a valid center property' error.

Comment: In your state route config, add this `return MapService.getData($stateParams.lat, $stateParams.lon).then(function(rsp){ console.log(rsp); return rsp; }).catch(function(err){console.log(err);})`.  See if that shows anything.  Also just for giggles, console log the $stateParams in that block as well, just to ensure you don't have an error that far up.

Comment: also just an FYI, you;re not passing `resolveMap` as an injectable to your controller.

Comment: @jusopi I added in that code in my resolve function in .config but it didn't do anything (or log anything to the console). And thanks for the advice, to add it as an injectable to my controller, would i just do something like:
.controller('MapsCtrl', ['resolveMap', ...]

Comment: It sounds like you're not hitting the state based on @charlieti's answer below.  That was a good catch.  In terms of the resolves, yes, you would inject with that syntax.  Basically anything declared in the resolve hash, those keys are then injectable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is you aren't using `<ui-view>` and have the template for that route right in the page using an `ng-controller`.

Then you use index.html as the template for the route.

In effect you have 2 instances of the controller and the app is not set up correctly at all regarding routing

The main ng-controller instance that runs within index.html will run regardless of the route and that's why it's not waiting for $stateParams or the route change

Set the page up as per router docs with it's own template and only a `<ui-view>` in index.html

Comment: Oh ok thanks for the advice, I will try that and post what happens.

Comment: I edited the question to show my new setup. I copied my index.html file to a new searchRadius.html file, and changed the template to searchRadius.html, and then just have the <ui-view> </ui-view> in index.html. As for setting up the page properly for routing, I am following my textbook closely. Could you please let me know what you mean when you say the controller will run no matter what the route is?

Comment: it means that when you declare controller in routing config you don't use `ng-controller` also. Each would create new instance. So when it was in index...it knew nothing about that route as `ng-controller`

Comment: So i should also use ng-controller as well as .controller in my first .config so that I create 2 instances?  How would I do that?

Comment: no...one or the other. Best to use the route to set it and then if you do a `resolve` it can be injected into that controller instance. A route resolve can't be injected into the one with `ng-controller`

Comment: You mean it can't be injected into: <div data-ng-controller="MapsCtrl"></div> that I have in index.html? I can't find where i am using ng-controller other than in index.html

Comment: right...hopefully you removed that controller reference

Comment: No you didn't. Replace that whole div in index with `<div ui-view></div>`. If map doesn't show might need to set height

Comment: Ok I replaced it (as you can see in the updated posted index.html) and I am still just coming up with a blank page: http://alainwebdesign.ca/pl4/#/49.2/-122.6

Comment: should set router up with an `otherwise` default rote. Also don't see request being made for template so resolve may be failing. Can add $stateChangeError handler and debug the resolve

Comment: I added that as a dependency in the .config function and got this error: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateChangeError

Comment: it's a broadcast event...see router docs (easiest to google it first). Needs to be put into a run block

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, i used your solution to have my main index, and render an html partial using routing. I had problems loading the page and it was fixed by taking out the resolve function: 
'resolve: {
              resolveMap: function (MapService, $stateParams) {
                  return MapService.getData($stateParams.lat, $stateParams.lon);
              }
          }'